# Product operation for cosets

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

In Artin's book, he gives a lemma that for a normal subgroup $N \subset G$ and cosets $aN$, $bN$, that the product set $(ab)N$ is also a coset; the proof simply uses the definition of normality:
$$(aN)(bN) = a(Nb)N = a(bN)N = (ab)(NN) = (ab)N.$$
My first question is how to put this proof in the context of demonstrating that this product operation is well-defined, which requires proving that if $aN = a'N$ and $bN = b'N$, then $abN = a'b’N$. I am not sure if this is in fact a proof of well-definedness and know that we can define a set product, say $AB$ of elements $ab$ where $a \in A, b \in B$. But we can't "use" this product unless it is well-defined, in which case it is by definition a coset, which leads me to beleive that Artin is in fact saying that this proof allows the operation to "work."

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Your description of “well-defined” is incorrect. You mean: if $aN=a’N$ and $bN=b’N$, then $abN = a’b’N$; not “$aN=bN$” as you wrote.

Comment: Thank you. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equations are just statements about equalities of sets. They use the following facts:

- For subsets $A$ and $B$ of $G$, $AB=\{ab\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$.
- For any subgroup $H$ of $G$, $HH=H$.
- For any *normal* subgroup $N$ of $G$, and every $x\in G$, $xN=Nx$ as sets.
- “Multiplication” of sets is associative: for any subsets $A$, $B$, and $C$ of $G$, $(AB)C = A(BC)$.

Using these we are not making a definition that the product of the set $aN$ and the the set $bN$ is going to be designated, by fiat, as $abN$. Rather, we are saying that the set $(aN)(bN)$ and the set $(ab)N$ are *equal* as sets. That means there is no issue of “well-definedness of the product”: we are making an assertion about equality of sets.

Because $(aN)(bN)=abN$ *as sets*; and $(a’N)(b’N)=a’b’N$, *as sets*, if $aN=a’N$ as sets and $bN=b’N$ as sets, then
$$abN = (aN)(bN) = (a’N)(b’N)=a’b’N.$$

We are not defining “products of cosets”, we are noting that the product of two cosets of a normal subgroup is again a coset of that normal subgroup; and along the way that the specific coset can be found by multiplying representatives. But we are just applying the definition of “multiplication of sets”, and the properties associated with it and with cosets of a normal subgroup.

This is different from starting from the set of cosets and saying “we define a multiplication of cosets by saying that $(aN)*(bN) = (ab)N$.” Such an assertion would require showing that it is well defined. Here, instead, we are using the product of sets, which has no definition issues.

Comment: If I am understanding your answer correctly, this result quoted from Artin about equality of sets directly implies well-definedness, so when we define coset multiplication as $aN bN = (ab)N$, it's a rather "natural" definition. Is that correct?

Comment: @JeremyS: In fact, there is no well-definedness issue at all if we are saying that this is an equality of sets, and you are not defining anything beyond the product of sets at all. It’s not technically a “natural definition” because it is not even a definition:  instead, it’s a statement that the set of cosets of $N$ is closed under the operation of “set product”, and that it can be computed this way.

Comment: So in that sense, I would never need to prove coset multiplication is well-defined at all, because by this set equality, it's true unless $N$ isn't normal, in which case the definition $aN = a'N$, $bN = b'N$ implies $abN = a'b'N$ becomes relevant for giving a counterexample. Is that correct?

Comment: @JeremyS: This proves that coset multiplication for normal subgroups is a binary operation (takes two cosets as inputs, outputs a coset); when $N$ isn’t normal, if you attempt to *define* an operation on left cosets that way, then the result is not a well-defined operation; and the product of cosets as sets is not always a coset, so it doesn’t define an operation.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: I misinterpreted the question posed, so what's below is largely unhelpful. I will keep my answer up regardless for anyone who would like to know how to prove that coset multiplication is well defined for context.**

To prove that coset multiplication is well defined I will prove the following statement adapted from the book Abstract Algebra by John Beachy and William D. Blair:

> Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, and let $a,b,c,d\in G$. If $aN = cN$ and $bN = dN$, then $abN = cdN$. Which implies that multiplication of left cosets is well defined.

**Proof:** Suppose that $aN = cN$ and $bN = dN$ then it is necessarily the case that $a^{-1}c\in N$ and $b^{-1}d\in N$. However, we know $N$ is normal and so $d^{-1}(a^{-1}c)d\in N$. Since $b^{-1}d\in N$ we have $(ab)^{-1}cd = (b^{-1}d)(d^{-1}a^{-1}cd)\in N$ which immediately implies that $abN = cdN$. As such, left coset multiplication is indeed well defined given that $N$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: I know how to prove that coset multiplication is well-defined, but what I don't fully understand is the relationship between this proof and the claim in Artin.

Comment: Oh I see I misinterpreted your question, I will make an edit to my 'answer' to reflect this.